# Upload file with html, and zipping or rar the file with password in PHP?

Tags: php, html, encryption, zip, rar

I cant figure out how how zip a file in PHP with password. The password will be the time and filename.

This is what i have done so far.

HTML Code for upload.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost/CSS/addfile.php" method="POST">
<div id="label">
<label>Upload File</label>
</div>
    <input name="doc" type="file" placeholder="Upload File Here" accept="files/topsecret/*" required>
<input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>
```

PHP code

```
function GetImageExtension($filetype)
{
    if(empty($filetype)) return false;
    switch($filetype)
    {
        case 'files/topsecret/bmp': return '.bmp';
        case 'files/topsecret/gif': return '.gif';
        case 'files/topsecret/jpeg': return '.jpg';
        case 'files/topsecret/png': return '.png';
        case 'files/topsecret/txt': return '.txt';
        case 'files/topsecret/doc': return '.doc';
        case 'files/topsecret/docx': return '.docx';
        case 'files/topsecret/pdf': return '.pdf';
        default: return false;
    }
}

$upFile = $_FILES['doc']['name'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['doc']['tmp_name'];
$ftype = $_FILES['doc']['type'];
$fileExt = GetImageExtension($ftype);

$filename = $upFile.$fileExt;
$target_path="files/topsecret/".$filename;
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$target_path);

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
$timefile = date("F j, Y g:ia");
$size = filesize($target_path);
$size = number_format($size / 1024, 2) . ' KB'; 

try{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO file(File_path,Date,Size,Name) VALUES ('".$target_path."','".$timefile."','".$size."','".$filename."')";

    if ($connection->query($sql)){

        echo"<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Upload Successfully');</script>";
        header("refresh:2;index.php");
    }else{
        echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Upload Not Successfully Inserted.');</script>";
    }
```

I have research a found a few function for php but dont know how to use it.
like.  ZipArchive::setEncryptionName ... but cant use it as i am using PHP version 7.1.8, in xampp.

Please help me explain on how to do it, as simple as possible. I need to encrypt the uploaded file with password using zip or rar. Plan to use hash the file name and time together and then setting it as the password.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You use it exactly how it's shown in the example http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.setencryptionname.php

Comment: I tried it, i cant use it as my version is 7.1.8 cause i am using xampp.
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method ZipArchive::setEncryptionName()

Answer (score 1):

First, a try block needs a catch.

Secondly, you shouldn't need the GetImageExtension function, $_FILES has the extension in the uploaded array, all you needed to do was `print_r($_FILES);` to be able to verify.

Sadly though, from what I read you can't encrypt a file just yet, you need to wait for [php 7.2](http://windows.php.net/download/) to be released to use `$zip->setEncryptionName;`.

I figured this out after writing out a bit of code, I figured it might be helpful nonetheless that's why I'm posting this answer.

You can look into: http://php.net/manual/en/filters.encryption.php, that's a good option to integrate into the code below, I don't have the time right now but it's fairly easy to do following their examples.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    upload($_FILES);
}

class Connection {
    protected $db = null;

    public function db(){
        if($this->db === null){
            try {
                $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=name; charset=utf8', user, password);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
        return $this->db;
    }
}

function upload($file_data){

    // calling this statically, don't suggest it
    $conn = Connetion::db();

    $name = $file_data['doc']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $file_data['doc']['tmp_name'];
    $extension = explode('/', $file_data['doc']['type']); // $extension[1] returns file type.
    $image_size = getimagesize($tmp_name);

    $file_name = $name . '.' . $extension[1];
    $target_path = "";

    if($image_size !== false){

        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        if ($zip->open('uploaded_file.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
            $zip->addFromString("text.txt", "#1 This is a test string added as testfilephp.txt.\n");
            $zip->setEncryptionName('text.txt', ZipArchive::EM_AES_256, 'secret'); // here we'd set the password 
            $zip->close();
            $zip_created = true;
        } else {
            $zip_created = false;
        }   

        // if zip was created and uploaded the file, then we upload it to the database
        if($zip_created == true){
            $sth = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO file (file_path, `date`, size, name) VALUES (:target_path, :time_file, :size, :file_name)');
            $sth->bindValue(':target_path', $target_path, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sth->bindValue(':time_file', date('m-d-Y H:i:s'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sth->bindValue(':target_path', $target_path, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sth->bindValue(':file_name', $file_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sth->execute();
        } else  {
            // here we can upload the error to the database or do nothing
        }
    }
}

?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="doc">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>
```